# Rendering 1 pixel lines with DrawingVisual

Tags: c#, wpf

I have seen several examples on rendering 1 pixel lines in WPF, but none seem to apply to my situation.  I am using DrawingVisual and DrawingContext to draw some shapes and RenderTargetBitmap and PngBitmapEncoder to generate the image.  In many cases the rectangles have a 2 pixel border even though I set it to 1.  I am guessing this is due to the resolution independent rendering that is used.

I have found several solutions but they are either in XAML or apply to drawing controls.  The closest thing I have found is XSnappingGuidelines/YSnappingGuidelines but I cannot find a single example of how to use it.  The documentation is very much lacking on these properties.

How do I disable the resolution independent rendering for DrawingVisual?

**UPDATE:**
Here is what I am trying to do:

Declare a DrawingVisual:

```
DrawingVisual mainTemplate = new DrawingVisual();
```

Get Context:

```
using (DrawingContext context = mainTemplate.RenderOpen())
```

Draw rectangle:

```
penToUse = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)), 1.0);
penToUse.DashStyle = DashStyles.Dash;
context.DrawRectangle(brushToUse, penToUse, new Rect(left, top, width, height));
```

Where do I set the rendering mode to align to pixels?

jorj

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some sample code.

Comment: Note that anything that is possible in XAML is also possible in code.

Comment: When you used rectangles, did you set the BorderThickness to only use 1 side? Like "0,1,0,0". Otherwise you'll get all the side drawn.

Answer (score 2):

In WPF, when you draw a line, the line is centered on the coordinates you specify. So if on a device with 96 DPI you draw a vertical line from 10, 10 to 10, 20 and the width of the pen is 1, the line will actually be drawn between 9.5 and 10.5 taking two pixels. If you want to align the line on the pixel edge, you need to shift it by 0.5. On a 120 DPI monitor, the width of the line should be 0.8 to take a single pixel, and you need to shift it by 0.4 to align on the pixel edge.

You do not have to use GuidelineSet because it doesn't do more than this simple shifting but unnecessarily complicates the code.

Comment: It's funny. When using Guidelines, one has to add or remove half the pen's width. It doesn't matter if you add or subtract, both work. But using the pen's coordinates doesn't. Strange.

Comment: Using Guidelines might be DPI independent ? After all the pen width and the correction of the guideline (see my comment above) is defined using the same value. Sorry, but the influence of DPI on WPF is really confusing. I guess not just for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've come to being able to render single pixels lines in WPF with a DrawingContext is this:

```
GuidelineSet guidelines = new GuidelineSet();
guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(_bgRect.Left - 0.5);
guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(_bgRect.Right + 0.5);
guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(_bgRect.Top - 0.5);
guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(_bgRect.Bottom + 0.5);
dc.PushGuidelineSet(guidelines);
dc.DrawRectangle(Background, _outlinePen, _bgRect);
if (BorderThickness.Left > 1)
    dc.DrawLine(_leftPen, _bgRect.TopLeft, _bgRect.BottomLeft);
if (BorderThickness.Top > 1)
    dc.DrawLine(_topPen, _bgRect.TopLeft, _bgRect.TopRight);
if (BorderThickness.Right > 1)
    dc.DrawLine(_rightPen, _bgRect.TopRight, _bgRect.BottomRight);
if (BorderThickness.Bottom > 1)
    dc.DrawLine(_bottomPen, _bgRect.BottomRight, _bgRect.BottomLeft);
dc.Pop();
```